# How to read parmeter value in rejection akka

Tags: akka, akka-http

I would like to read the parameter value in rejection:

```
parameter(paramName.as[Int] ? default).recover[Tuple1[Int]]{
 case Seq(MalformedQueryParamRejection(paramName, _, _)) =>
       complete(invalidQueryParameterError(paramName, ????))
}
```

instead ??? i would like to pass our param value
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at `akka.http.scaladsl.server.ParameterDirectives`, you can see how the query parameters are handled via `handleParamResult`. It seems that the parameter value is not passed along, so you cannot actually extract the wrong value from the Rejection object.

However, there are some standard messages that Akka Http provides with regards to the result of processing of the query parameters. The only solution that comes to my mind is to parse that response if you really need the parameter value. However, I don't see why you would do that.

As an example, [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.1/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html#deserialized-parameter), you can see the expected message that Akka returns along the rejection when a query parameter is malformed. Still, I don't think is a good practice to rely on these standard messages.